# Heroku-forward error on proxy server termination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku-forward is working beautifully for our app!  The only issue is when restarting the app/dynos, we see this error in the logs:

```
2013-06-09T22:21:19.293142+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 41124 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2013-06-09T22:21:19.831067+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2013-06-09T22:21:19.839532+00:00 app[web.1]: Terminating ProxyServer
2013-06-09T22:21:19.841418+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
2013-06-09T22:21:19.876112+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:129:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
2013-06-09T22:21:19.951354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
2013-06-09T22:21:22.853675+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:21:22.853347 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2013-06-09T22:21:23.509927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-09T22:21:23.881194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-09T22:22:38.222124+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:22:38.221884 #5]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn-20130609-2-130wmqw.sock fd=8
2013-06-09T22:22:38.301586+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:22:38.301333 #5]  INFO -- : master process ready
2013-06-09T22:22:38.718708+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:22:38.718418 #13]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2013-06-09T22:22:38.795721+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:22:38.795417 #7]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2013-06-09T22:22:38.813390+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-09T22:22:38.813064 #10]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

It doesn't seem to be catastrophic though -- as you can see at the end, the dyno does start very quickly, and the proxy does end up working fine (after about a minute... lots of gems to load).  The error message is just a little worrisome.  Anyone seen this before?

**UPDATE:**

Here are our rackup files, per the Heroku-forward readme:

```
# my_app.ru
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run MyApp::Application
```

and

```
# config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

$stdout.sync = true
Bundler.require(:rack)

port = (ARGV.first || ENV['PORT'] || 3000).to_i
env = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

require 'em-proxy'
require 'logger'
require 'heroku-forward'
require 'heroku/forward/backends/unicorn'

application = File.expand_path('../my_app.ru', __FILE__)
config_file = File.expand_path('../config/unicorn.rb', __FILE__)
backend = Heroku::Forward::Backends::Unicorn.new(application: application, env: env, config_file: config_file)
proxy = Heroku::Forward::Proxy::Server.new(backend, host: '0.0.0.0', port: port)
proxy.forward!
```

Answer (score 0):

That issue is probably not happening in the startup of the new dyno: its more likely in the shutdown of the old dyno. Seen similar issues when the Rack configuration file doesn't actually run the app (`config.ru` should end with a `to_app` call). Are you using a custom `config.ru` file?

Comment: Odd: looks fine. Try using `run Rails::application` in my_app.ru? Looking at this commit, that may help: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9669